# Как передать данные через глобальную сеть, используя код на Python?

Tags: python

Я пытался сделать передачу данных через библиотеку socket, но я не смог. Как можно передать данные, не используя локальную сеть? Если можно использовать socket для передачи, то в чём моя проблема?
Вот мои лучшие коды для передачи данных (работает только в локальной сети):

```
import threading, socket, time
Address, Server = [socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 5000], socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
Server.bind(tuple(Address))
print("Запущен сервер с адресом: " + ":".join([Address[0], str(Address[1])]))
Users, Ended = list(), False
def Joining():
    pass
    global Users, Server, Ended
    while not Ended:
        Ended = True
        Server.listen(1)
        User_Index, User_Address = Server.accept()
        User = {"User":User_Index, "Address":User_Address}
        print("Присоеденился пользователь с адресом: " + str(User["Address"]))
        del User_Index, User_Address
        Users.append(User)
        del User
        if Ended == True:
            time.sleep(1)
        if Ended == True:
            print("Остановлено.")
Joining = threading.Thread(target=Joining)
Joining.start()
while True:
    Ended = False
    for User in Users:
        User["User"].sendall(input("Напишите сообщение. >>> ").encode())
        Data = None
        while True:
            Data = User["User"].recv(1024).decode()
            if Data != None:
                break
        print("Пришло сообщение: " + Data)
        del Data
```

```
import socket, time
Server = socket.socket()
Host, Port = "", 5000
Server.connect((Host, Port))
print("Подключено!")
while True:
    Data = None
    while True:
        Data = Server.recv(1024).decode()
        if Data != None:
            break
    print("Пришло сообщение: " + Data)
    del Data
    Server.sendall(input("Напишите сообщение. >>> ").encode())
```

Comment: Думаю, я не один, кто тоже не знает. XD

Comment: Внешний ip - это ip вашего роутера, а не компьютера, где вы запускаете сервер. Чтобы работало, нужно на роутере настроить проброс порта.